# Hibernate postgres auto increment after manual insert

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, flyway

I have a basic spring application, with a simple entity. I have a flyway script, to create the postgres table, and add some starting data.

```
create table user (
  id serial primary key,
  username varchar  (50) unique not null,
  password varchar  (150) not null
);

insert into user (id, username, password) values (1, 'name', 'somehashed');
insert into etc...
```

I've set up my entity as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, columnDefinition = "serial")
private Long id;
...
other fields, constructor, getters setters etc...
```

My problem is, that on start-up, the basic entities are persisted by flyway, but upon trying to save a new entity, hibernate tries to give it the ID 1, although it is already given to another one.

I tried it also with SEQUENCE strategy, the problem didn't get solved.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, problem was that I specified explicitly the ID I wanted to give while the insert script, and I didn't let postgres do the magic...